# ax.annotate not annotating in correct order?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code to create annotations for a plot. I basically want to plot the win ratio and the win percentage for each page type. But the annotations are labeling in an incorrect order.

Heres some reproducible code. Does anyone know why it's not in the correct order?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = [['Cat page', 'No Fields', 0, 2, 0.000000],
        ['Cat page', 'Fields Included', 2, 2, 1.000000],
        ['Web page', 'No Fields', 3, 6, 0.500000],
        ['Web page', 'Fields Included', 3, 6, 0.500000],
        ['Home page', 'No Fields', 5, 13, 0.384615],
        ['Home page', 'Fields Included', 8, 13, 0.615385]
        ]

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['page_type',
                              'signup_field',
                              'win_count',
                              'total_wins',
                              'win_percent']
)


plt.figure(figsize=(8,7)) 

ax = sns.barplot(
    x = "win_count",
    y = "page_type",
    hue = "signup_field",
    data = data,
)


n=0
for patch in ax.patches:
  w, h = patch.get_width(), patch.get_height()
  w = 0 if np.isnan(w) else 1 if w == 1 else np.round(np.float(w) ,3)
  y = patch.get_y()

  ax.text(w , h/2+y, '({},{}/{})'.format(data.win_percent[n], data.win_count[n], data.total_wins[n]), va='center')
  n+=1
```

Here's an image of the incorrect labeling. For example for Home page (no fields) the label should be (0.384615) 5/13 but it's giving the label for web page for some reason.
[image]